# Set up recurring billing for payments pro in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use recurring billing for website payments pro using the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call.

I'm testing my code in the sandbox, but I get the error "DPRP is disabled for this merchant".  I can't seem to find where in the account to enable recurring payments.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the different types of accounts. Recurring Payments (NOT recurring billing. these are 2 different products) was offered with older PayPal accounts. With the new accounts, you should be using the Payflow gateway to perform Recurring Billing transactions.

To do this, first you need to make a Payflow test account. This can be done by doing Part 1, 2 and 3 from this article:
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929

After you have a test Payflow account, you can follow this recurring billing guide here to set up recurring billing:
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_RecurringBilling_Guide.pdf

Comment: Okay, but I've already written code for the Pro API - there's got to be some way to do this.

Comment: If the code is written already, yes there is a way to do it. Just contact sales and let them know you need a "3.0" account. This account will allow for DPRP.